# Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification (xamarin.forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have bound one list from web service. First time only 5 items are loaded and then when user scroll the list view other 5 items are loaded. Every thing is working fine but I am facing issue in one scenario.
**First time when List is bound (don't do scrolling) and if immediately I clicked on some list item then "ItemTepped" event is fired and page should be navigated to other page but problem is it showing me error as below image.**

[image: Error Image]

I have put Active indicator for loading.

***This code is in xamarin.forms (Portable library). This is not xamarin.Android project.***

```
public partial class NewsGalleryListPage : ContentPage
    {
        int totalItems = 0;
        decimal MaxIndex = 0;
        int index = 0;
        List<Newslist> NewsList;
        public NewsGalleryListPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            NewsGalleryLists.ItemTapped += NewsGalleryLists_ItemTapped;
            NewsGalleryLists.ItemAppearing += NewsGalleryLists_ItemAppearing1;
            loadingIndicator.IsVisible = true;
            loading.IsRunning = true;
            loading.IsVisible = true;
            CallWebServiceForNewsGalleryList(index);
        }

        private void NewsGalleryLists_ItemAppearing1(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (totalItems != 0)
                {
                    MaxIndex = Math.Ceiling(((decimal)totalItems) / 5);
                    if (index < MaxIndex)
                    {
                        if (NewsList != null && e.Item != null && e.Item == NewsList[NewsList.Count - 1])
                        {
                            index++;
                            if (index != MaxIndex)
                            {
                                loadingIndicator.IsVisible = true;
                                loading.IsVisible = true;
                                loading.IsRunning = true;
                                CallWebServiceForNewsGalleryList(index);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        private void NewsGalleryLists_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedNewsGalleryListItem = sender as Xamarin.Forms.ListView;
            var obj = selectedNewsGalleryListItem.SelectedItem as CMO.ServicesClasses.Newslist;
            Navigation.PushAsync(new CMO.Gallery.NewsGalleryDetail(obj));
        }
        public async void CallWebServiceForNewsGalleryList(int index)
        {
            try
            {
                string lang = "en";

                if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("Language"))
                {
                    lang = Application.Current.Properties["Language"] as string;
                    // do something with i
                }
                List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("lang",lang));
                values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("title", ""));
                values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("index", Convert.ToString(index)));
                values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("limit", "5"));
                var response = await GeneralClass.GetResponse<CMO.ServicesClasses.RootObjectNewsGalleryList>("http://14.141.36.212/maharastracmo/api/getnewslist", values);
                if (response != null)
                {

                    if (NewsList == null || index==0)
                    {
                        NewsList = new List<Newslist>();
                    }
                    for(int i = 0; i < response.newslist.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var ObjectNewslist = new Newslist();
                        ObjectNewslist.page_id = response.newslist[i].page_id;
                        ObjectNewslist.title = response.newslist[i].title;
                        ObjectNewslist.date = response.newslist[i].date;
                        ObjectNewslist.news_photo = response.newslist[i].news_photo;
                        ObjectNewslist.content = response.newslist[i].content;
                        NewsList.Add(ObjectNewslist);
                    }
                    totalItems = response.total_results;
                    NewsGalleryLists.RowHeight = 100;
                    var x = NewsGalleryLists.RowHeight;
                    this.Title = AppResources.LNewsGallery;
                    NewsGalleryLists.ItemsSource = NewsList;
                }
            }
            catch (WebException exception)
            {
            }
            loading.IsVisible = false;
            loading.IsRunning = false;
            loadingIndicator.IsVisible = false;
        }
    }
```

I have gone through following link

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23124/proper-way-to-update-the-tableviews-sections-content
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21994/threading-in-xamarin-forms

I have tried

```
Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() =>
        {});

Task.Run(() => { });
```

I don't know how to handle thread in xamarin forms as beginner level.

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens when you use `TemplateSelector`, but creating a new one for each row. **Create one instance** of  `TemplateSelector` and use it.

Comment: I have only one DataTemplate. Why we should use DataTemplateSelector? I think its threading Issues

Comment: I have almost solved the issue. I just replace "ObservableCollection" with "List". INotifyChanged property is inherited in ObservableCollection. but now problem is my ActiveIndicator(Loading) is not displayed.